# Destroying Chart js within useEffect - React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am having trouble destroying the previous chart when the a new chart is created.

The issue is that if   `if(myChart) myChart.destroy()`  never fires. Perhaps this is because the `myChart` variable only exists within the `useEffect`.

While the `myChart` variable could be allocated to a state, you wouldn't be able to call `destroy()` on a state directly.

So how would you go about this?

The below example renders a pie or a bar chart depending on the value of `graphType`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default function GraphMaker({ graphType }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

        if (myChart) myChart.destroy()

        if (graphType === "pie") {
            console.log(myChart)

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "pie",
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "# of Votes",
                            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                "Red",
                                "Blue",
                                "Yellow",
                                "Green",
                                "Purple",
                                "Orange"
                            ],
                            borderColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        } 
        else if (graphType === "bar") {
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "# of Votes",
                            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                "Red",
                                "Blue",
                                "Yellow",
                                "Green",
                                "Purple",
                                "Orange"
                            ],
                            borderColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        }
    }, [graphType])

    return (
        <>
            <canvas id="myChart" />
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new docs they also use this, they solved it by destroying the chart in the return of the use effect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cfg = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: [
          'Red',
          'Blue',
          'Yellow'
        ],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'My First Dataset',
          data: [300, 50, 100],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
          ],
          hoverOffset: 4
        }]
      }
    };
    const chart = new Chart(canvas.current.getContext('2d'), cfg);
    return () => chart.destroy();
  });
```

Link to their doc with live example: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/doughnut/

Comment: Thanks for this. This seemed to fix the issues i was having